# length and informat different from format

Tags: sas, format

Basically, I want the `ETHNIC` variable in the format where `length`, `format` and `informat` are all `$22`. However when I run the following code and check the variable attributes it states that the `format` is `$22` but the `length` is `2` and `informat` is `$2`

```
data ETHNIC;        
set ethnicity;
format ETHNIC $ 22.;    /*the format I need, but it doesn't seem to work as I wanted*/
    if ETHNIC='1' then do;
        ETHNIC='Hispanic or Latino';
    end;
    if ETHNIC='2' then do;
        ETHNIC='Not Haspanic or Latino';
    end;
    keep SUBJID ETHNIC;
    run;
```

how do I get all three to be `$22`

Comment: can you show us  where is the code you ran. As you have mentioned when i run the following code. how long is your character, if it is 2 then you should not use increase length, as this will cost unneccesary waste of space.

Comment: @kiran I have attached the code above. my characters are 22 in length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already had ethnic variable with length 2 , it took that length. So you need to overwrite that length by using length or format statement before set statement.

```
data ETHNIC; 
 format ETHNIC $ 22.   ;
set ethnicity;

if ETHNIC='1' then do;
    ETHNIC='Hispanic or Latino';
end;
if ETHNIC='2' then do;
    ETHNIC='Not Haspanic or Latino';
end;

run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you have the same name for the input & output field "ETHNIC" you can't change the length because the compiler thinks you are referring to the input field.

Solution:

- Rename input field,
- Use length, format & informat statements.

Code:

```
/*Creating dummy data*/
data ethnicity;
input SUBJID $ ETHNIC $;
cards;
A 1
B 1
C 2
;;;
run;
data ETHNIC;        
set ethnicity (rename=(ETHNIC=ETHNIC1)); /*rename ETHNIC to ETHNIC1 to avoid conflict  */
format ETHNIC $ 22.;    /*the format I need, but it doesn't seem to work as I wanted*/
informat ETHNIC $ 22.;  /* Define Informat here*/
length ETHNIC $ 22.;    /* Define Length here*/
    if ETHNIC1='1' then do;
        ETHNIC='Hispanic or Latino';
    end;
    if ETHNIC1='2' then do;
        ETHNIC='Not Haspanic or Latino';
    end;
    keep SUBJID ETHNIC;
run;
/*Check log for table definition*/
proc sql;
describe table ETHNIC;
quit;
```

Output:

[image]

Log: To confirm field length , format , informat

```
create table WORK.ETHNIC( bufsize=4096 )
   SUBJID char(8),
   ETHNIC char(22) format=22. informat=22.
  );
```